# Show that an iterative method converges to sqrt(a)

Tags: real-analysis, newton-series

Okay, i think i solved it but it seems too easy:

$\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}$ $x_n = \lim_\limits{x\to \infty}$ $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{a}$
the iterative method is:
$x_{n+1}$ = $\frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3a)}{3x_n^2 + a}$
I let $x_n$ be $\sqrt{a}.$ And crunched the equation. Is this right, and if not, what did i do wrong?

Comment: I think your computations are "correct" but don't form a complete argument. You could just as well let $x_n=-\sqrt{a}$ or $x_n=0$. Why doesn't the sequence converge to one of those values? Did you specify a starting spot? An $x_0$, that is?

Comment: I did not specify a $x_0$ so, should specify it as $\sqrt{a}$? That way the next $x_n$ value of $x_1$ will be $\sqrt{a}$ from the first calculation? If so, its seems as though this is a giant loop where all values are $\sqrt{a}$ which makes me think this is wrong.

Comment: The sequence converges to $\sqrt{a}$ if you start from any $x_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $\left| \frac{x_0 - \sqrt{a}}{x_0 + \sqrt{a}}\right| < 1$.

Comment: @UndeadCosmonaut Achille touches on a good point - the point to which the process converges depends on the starting point. Other starting values might converge to $-\sqrt{a}$. No values will converge to zero without hitting it exactly, even though the calculation you did works for $x_n=0$.

Comment: I should clarify, this was my mistake for not adding it in the OP. The question asks to show it converges to $\sqrt{a}$ for any positive integer $a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing.

I assume $a>0$. Suppose the sequence defined by $x_{0}$ and
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}\left(x_{n}^{2}+3a\right)}{3x_{n}^{2}+a}\text{ for }n\geq0\tag{1}
$$
is well-defined and has limit $x$ such that $3x^{2}+a\neq0$ and
$x\neq0$. Taking limits on both sides of (1),
$$
x=\frac{x\left(x^{2}+3a\right)}{3x^{2}+a}.
$$
Dividing both sides by $x$ (we can do this since we assumed $x\neq0$),
$$
1=\frac{x^{2}+3a}{3x^{2}+a}.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
x^{2}=a
$$
and hence $x=\pm \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: Well it asked to use the iterative method for n = 0,1... and show that it converges o $\sqrt{a}$ for any positive $a$. I based it off a similar question regarding convergence, i found on math.stackexchange where another user found the method order.

Comment: @UndeadCosmonaut: achille hui's answer is actually better than mine, since achille hui does not make any assumptions about convergence of the sequence a priori, like I do!

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt{a}$, you have only shown $\sqrt{a}$ is a fixed point of the iteration.

In general, when someone set up a sequence $x_n$ by iteration of a function $f(x)$ and ask one to show the sequence $x_n$ converges to some number $\alpha$. What it really means is

> Given a function $f : D \to D$ where $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ ( or $\mathbb{C}$ or whatever appropriate).
>   **For suitable choice** of $x_0 \in D$, the sequence defined by the iteration
>   $$x_{n+1} = f(x_n), \quad\text{ for } n \ge 0$$ 
>   will converge to $\alpha$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = \alpha$, independent of precise choice of $x_0$.

If the explicit range of $x_0$ is not given, it usually mean either
"for $x_0$ sufficiently close to $\alpha$" or "for all $x_0$ falling in some obvious choice of domain".

For the problem at hand, $\displaystyle\;f(x) = \frac{x(x^2+3a)}{3x^2+a}$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{a}$.

To show $x_n$ converges to $\alpha = \sqrt{a}$, showing $f(\alpha) = \alpha$ is not enough. At the least, you need to show there is some $\epsilon > 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = \alpha$ whenever $|x_0 - \alpha| < \epsilon$.

It turns out we can do much better than that.

For any $a > 0$, we are going to show for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re x_0 > 0$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = \alpha = \sqrt{a}$.

Consider following auxiliary sequence 
$$y_n = \frac{x_n - \alpha}{x_n + \alpha}
\quad\iff\quad x_n = \alpha \left( \frac{1+y_n}{1-y_n} \right)
$$
It is easy to verify 
$$y_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n+1}-\alpha}{x_{n+1} + \alpha}
= 
\frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3\alpha^2) -\alpha(3x_n^2+\alpha^2)}{x_n(x_n^2 + 3\alpha^2) +\alpha(3x_n^2+\alpha^2)}
= \left(\frac{x_n-\alpha}{x_n+\alpha}\right)^3
= y_n^3
$$
Since this is true for all $n$, we obtain following closed form for $y_n$ and hence for $x_n$:

$$y_n = y_0^{3^n}\quad\implies\quad
x_n = \alpha \left( \frac{1+y_0^{3^n}}{1-y_0^{3^n}} \right)
$$

When $\Re x_0 > 0$, we have $|y_0|= \left|\frac{x_0 - \alpha}{x_0 + \alpha}\right| < 1$. This forces $|y_n| = |y_0|^{3^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
As a result,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \alpha \left(\frac{1+0}{1-0}\right) = \alpha = \sqrt{a}$$

By a similar argument, when $\Re x_0 < 0$, $|y_0| > 1$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha\left(\frac{y_0^{-3^n}+1}{y_0^{-3^n}-1}\right) = \alpha\left(\frac{0+1}{0-1}\right) = -\alpha = -\sqrt{a}$$